# Is it safe to remove the "Mail and Calendar" app when I am using Outlook?

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook

My question could be expressed in the title, however, here's some background.
I have my work computer set-up to dual-boot Windows and Linux. Since the medium-sized SSD needs to host two operating systems along with useful software for actual work, I need to economize on disk use.

Since my work-place provides the Office software suite, emails and the calendar are taken care of by Microsoft Outlook. Hence, "Mail and Calendar" is somewhat superflous for me.

I noticed that "Mail and Calendar" is reported to take up nearly half a gigabyte, which isn't nothing.

With Windows being Windows, I am a bit reluctant to remove apps that Microsoft in its wisdom considered to promote to "standard".

Is it safe to remove "Mail and Calendar", or is it somehow embedded into Windows such that I create breakage somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another form of wisdom for Microsoft. If its crucial, you cannot remove it easily.

If you go to Settings -> Apps, and there is no remove option, don't attempt to remove it. If it is there, you can safely remove it without any problem.

The Mail and Calendar app is one that you can remove from there, so its safe to do so, given that you are using Outlook. If you want it back in the future, you can go to the Windows Store, search for it and install it again.

With that reasoning, try look at Microsoft Photos. You'll see that the remove button is grayed out.

If the button Remove for Mail and Calendar is grayed out for anyone else that visits this answer, it may be that its greyed out if you have still set it as default app for mail.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the greyed out remove buttons for vital things like the "X-Box Game Bar". So, while I share your sentiment "if it's easy to remove, it should be safe to remove"; am I nevertheless cautious. With the "Game Bar" not appearing vital, and nonetheless not being easy to remove, there's your counter example.

Comment: The game bar is actually vital in the sense that its tied up in windows system, showing up if you press win+g and gives control to a mixer and stuff. But I removed Mail and Calendar from my computer if that eases your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook and the Mail and Calendar app are not connected, so you can remove them.

Open Settings, and click/tap on the Apps icon.

Click/tap on App & features on the left side, click/tap on a Windows app or desktop app on the right side you want to uninstall, and click/tap on the Uninstall button. (see screenshot below)
[image]

If you think my answer is helpful, please kindly accept it to help other people.